# Continuous surjection from simple closed curve to unit circle

Tags: general-topology

My goal is to proof that every simple closed curve is homeomorphic to unit circle. I also have nice theorem for it.

But, I cannot do it before I find continuous surjection.

Let $f([0,1])\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2}$ be the simple closed curve ($f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$).

How I can find continuous surjection $g:f([0,1])\rightarrow S^{1}$?

Comment: Write a map in the other direction.

Comment: So I should take advantage of the mapping from $[0,1]$ to $S^1$? If that is $h$, then we have $t\mapsto (\cos (2\pi t),\sin (2\pi t))$. Now we should find such $g$ that $g \circ h = f$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are homeomorphic to the quotient space $[0,1] / R$ where $R$ is the equivalence relation that only identifies $0$ and $1$ and no other points. For the circle you can use the map induced by the standard parametrisation, and $f$ has a similar role. And two spaces homeomorphic to the same space are homeomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jordan-Schoenflies Curve Theorem.